# Link in browser address bar when using unicode/utf8/win1251 characters

Tags: javascript, php, html, unicode

I use the following link conversion:

```
$s = "Активные";
urlencode(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', $s);
```

As the result i get in browser address bar this:

```
site.com/catalog/%C0%EA%F2%E8%E2%ED%FB%E5
```

But i need to convert it into this:

```
site.com/catalog/Активные
```

The same way uses Wikipedia, when you search in russian it will pass encoded string, but in the link it will show all correct:

```
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA][1]
```

Please advise how to achieve it..

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I believe the `%FE` are the way that it converts encoding. Just like how `%20` in a url is a space

Comment: What encoding are you using for the page that is loaded into that browser tab?

Comment: Yes, Noah, but in Wikipedia it will show all correct.. I pass the parameter (it's in russian) so it supposed to show it correct in the browser address bar..

Comment: I use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: try -- string utf8_encode ( string $data ) -- and then added to the end of the url --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: @Tasos, no it won't work like this. The way i pass the parameter is correct. The only not correct is how it looks in my browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The standard that most browsers use for showing Unicode in the address bar is [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_resource_identifier). In this spec path parts are encoded in UTF-8, not cp1251.

Omit the `iconv` step to leave the string in UTF-8 encoding and you should get:

```
http://example.com/catalog/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5
```

which will display as:

```
http://example.com/catalog/Активные
```

in the address bars of most browsers (exception: IE under typical circumstances).